# Is there a way to set an specific display at chromium launch options?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, puppeteer, chromium

I'm doing a node aplication with Puppeteer and I need to set an Xvfb display as the main display for the browser, but i can't seem to find any way to do this.
The closest I got to what I want is to use '--use-fake-device-for-media-stream', but I want to set as a real device instead of just a test video.
There is anyway I can do this ?

Answer (score 2):

This solution has worked for me:

```
# install the package
apt-get install -y xvfb

# set display variable
export DISPLAY=:0

# start Xvfb daemon in the background (only once)
/usr/bin/Xvfb :0 -screen 0 1024x768x24 &

# wait a bit to let it come up (only once)
sleep 5

# add prefix "xvfb-run" to "node" or "python" script
xvfb-run node myscript.js
# or
xvfb-run python myscript.py
```

Don't forget to set  { headless: false } when launching puppeteer.

Source: https://anti-captcha.com/apidoc/articles/how-to-integrate-the-plugin

Comment: wow, that actually started my script with xvfb, thanks!
but actually, doesn't solved the entire problem. I will use this node aplication to share my screen, so I'm using   '--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream' to skip the select screen prompt, and when I start with xvfb it doesn't do anything. Any ideia on how to solve this ?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what you are trying to do? Like, what steps you want to perform with puppeteer. Maybe it's just me, but it surely may help others as well to understand your problem better

Comment: Ok, sorry for the confuse question.
I'm actually doing a selfbot that shares it screen at discord, but when you click the 'Share your screen button' a pop up appears, and puppeteer can't handle it, so it's impossible to do it without the  '--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream' argument, which when launching the script with Xvfb, doesn't do anything.
But with the '--use-fake-device-for-media-stream', it works perfectly fine, but with the test video only, and I want to set the Xvfb display to work like the test video.
Hope that gives some light to the problem.

Comment: Do you need to set headless to false? I'm trying to run headless chromium and my error is `ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(536)] Failed to open an X11 connection.`

Answer (score 0):

Puppeteer is headless (without a display) by nature, but you can set default viewports, pixel ratios, etc to simulate the devices you're testing against using [`page.emulate()`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v13.0.0&show=api-pageemulateoptions) or [`page.setViewport()`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v13.0.0&show=api-pagesetviewportviewport).